# Issue retrieving Jsonb column data from PostgreSQL using jdbc

Tags: java, json, postgresql, spring-boot, jdbc

I'm currently facing an issue for retrieving data from a jsonb column in my postgresql database using spring boot & jdbc. The request that is generated by jdbc is making a outer join and looking for a table that doest not exists instead of a column. Here is my code:

Class:

```
@Table("work_table")
public class Work implements Serializable {
        @Id
        Integer id;

        @NotBlank
        String title;

        @NotNull
        Category category;

        @Column("creationdate") 
        LocalDateTime creationDate;

        @Column("lastupdated")
        LocalDateTime lastUpdated;

        @Column("metadata")
        @jakarta.persistence.Column(columnDefinition = "jsonb")
        @Convert(converter = MetadataConverter.class)
        Metadata metadata;
}

@Embeddable
public class Metadata implements Serializable {
    Integer id;
    String name;
}
```

Repository:

```
import org.springframework.data.repository.ListCrudRepository;

public interface WorkRepository extends ListCrudRepository<Work, Integer> {
}
```

Controller:

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/api/work")
public class WorkController {
    private final WorkRepository repository;

    WorkController(WorkRepository repository) {
        this.repository = repository;
    }

    @GetMapping
    public List<Work> findAll() { return repository.findAll(); }
}
```

Any ideas of what am i doing wrong here? Thanks in advance! :)